# Maven publication 'maven' cannot include multiple components / Publication only contains dependencies and/or constraints without a version

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, maven-plugin

Here is my project structure:

```
- snow
  - snow-lib
    - snow-base-util
    - snow-web-common
  - snow-web
    - snow-user
```

This is the code, very simple. https://github.com/site-weic/snow

### case 1

When I configure **snow-web-common** publish to Maven Local, it published successfully(branch [**case1**](https://github.com/site-weic/snow/tree/case1)).

- snow-lib/snow-base-util/build.gradle is empty
- snow-lib/snow-web-common/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    api 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    api project(':snow-lib:snow-base-util')
}
java {
    withJavadocJar()
    withSourcesJar()
}
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = project.group
            artifactId = project.name
            version = project.version

            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

### case 2

But configuring **snow-base-util** will report an error(branch [**case2**](https://github.com/site-weic/snow/tree/case2))

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':snow-lib:snow-web-common'.
> Maven publication 'maven' cannot include multiple components

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

- snow-lib/snow-base-util/build.gradle

```
java {
    withJavadocJar()
    withSourcesJar()
}
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = project.group
            artifactId = project.name
            version = project.version

            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

- snow-lib/snow-web-common/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    api 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    api project(':snow-lib:snow-base-util')
}
java {
    withJavadocJar()
    withSourcesJar()
}
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = project.group
            artifactId = project.name
            version = project.version

            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

### case 3

Another error will be reported when I configure to publish two projects at the same time(branch [**case3**](https://github.com/site-weic/snow/tree/case3))

```
Execution failed for task ':generateMetadataFileForMavenPublication'.
> Invalid publication 'maven':
    - Publication only contains dependencies and/or constraints without a version. You need to add minimal version information, publish resolved versions (https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:resolved_dependencies) or reference a platform (https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/platforms.html)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

- snow-lib/snow-base-util/build.gradle

```
java {
    withJavadocJar()
    withSourcesJar()
}
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = project.group
            artifactId = project.name
            version = project.version

            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

- snow-lib/snow-web-common/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    api 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    api project(':snow-lib:snow-base-util')
}
```

How to fix the gradle configuration?
And, what is the best practice for gradle to package multi-module projects? Could you please provide some reference projects at Github or Books?
Thanks!!!‍♂️

Comment: I don't know why, but when I add at least one explicit version dependency to the project(such as org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30) ，which has already been set in root/build.gradle, and then set unique task name such as `"$project.name"(MavenPublication)`, I can publish